# How to password protect a PDF file using Perl?

Tags: perl, pdf, password-protection

I'm want to add password protection to PDF files generated by my application. Are there any CPAN modules I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [CPAN module](http://search.cpan.org/~cdolan/CAM-PDF-1.52/lib/CAM/PDF/Decrypt.pm) that should help. Also you should probably be aware of the fact that PDF password protection is kinda weak...